# no rows to aggregate in R

Tags: r

I have a column in my data that is split by poor, Average and Good. I'm looking to find the Max and the Min number in a different column when one of those categories is selected.

This is what I have for the code:

```
aggregate(as.numeric(data_gt$Category), list(exptCount=data_gt$Employment_Rate),max)
```

Is there an easier way to do this, even if it takes more commands to individually get the max min for each category?

Thanks for your help, I'm new to R so still learning the basics.

Comment: You're getting the error as indicated in the question title?  Please add some data so the error may be demonstrated.  See here for tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, got it sorted

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error message if you specified incorrect variable name (`data_gt$Category` instead of `data_gt$category`).